# Five cards are numbered $1$ to $5$

Tags: probability

There are $5$ cards numbered $1$ to $5$, one number on one card. Two cards are drawn at random without repetition and $x$, sum of numbers on the cards is noted. Find the mean and variance of $x$.

Does this question make sense at all? I am not able to interpret its language. Please provide some insight.

Comment: "Without repetition" is used here to mean "without replacement." "Ar random" is meant to be interpreted as meaning that all "hands" of $2$ cards are equally likely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes sense. In other words, you have 5 cards, and you take 1 card (without putting it back) and then take another card. This is "without replacement". We can make a table of how the pairs add up

\begin{array}{c|r|c|c|c|c|c}
+&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
1&\mathsf X&3&4&5&6\\\hline
2&3&\mathsf X&5&6&7\\\hline
3&4&5&\mathsf X&7&8\\\hline
4&5&6&7&\mathsf X&9\\\hline
5&6&7&8&9&\mathsf X
\end{array}
where the first column shows the values of the first draw, the first row shows the value of the second draw, each cell is the sum of the pair, and $\mathsf X$ denotes sums that cannot happen.

Let $X$ be sum of the two draws. Then we can construct the distribution table of $X$. Since each pair is equally likely, we have
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & 3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline
P(X = x)&\dfrac{2}{20}&\;&\;&\;&\;&\;
\end{array}
You can complete the table, and then compute the expectation and variance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it means, not an answer to the question, which is what you appear to be looking for.

Imagine that there are five cards, as so $$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$$

You pick two distinct cards, say $1$, $2$. Then $x$ is the sum of $1+2$.

So, make a note of how much each $x$ appears. For example, $3$ will appear only $1$ time, and so on. Write down these values of $x$-and how much they appear in a graph.

Find the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) and [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of the statistics.

Comment: Could you explain the line "Two cards are drawn at random without repetition"?

Comment: @H.P.Das It means that you pick two distinct cards randomnly.

Comment: @MXYMXY It means there is no use of probability here. I mean if we get 2 and 3, the we don't have to consider probability of getting 2 and 3?

Comment: @Ananya I think that is what random means. There is the equal chance of  $(1,2)$ appearing as well as $(2,3)$ appearing.

Comment: @Ananya Yes the phrase "at random" usual means "selected with no bias".